# How to reduce OneDrive storage?

Tags: onedrive, storage

I'm using a Windows Lumia 640XL Windows Phone.

Just recently it was finally updated because I needed enough storage space. After the update, my phone is almost full (while not having that many apps installed).

Now WhatsApp doesn't work anymore because it needs 100 MB of free space (why?).

My 'This device' is now using 7.28 GB out of 7.28 GB. I already moved all possible apps to the SD card. System & reserved is 4.36 GB and cannot be changed. Apps & Games is 2.71 GB.

Within Apps & Games, OneDrive is by far most using the most 656 MB). Going to advanced options, the Reset button is disabled, and no add-ons are installed.

I removed (most) onedrive offline files.

How can I reduce the storage of OneDrive? And how can I change the offline onedrive files to SD?

Comment: The only way I was able to solve the space/update problem was: backup, factory reset, update, restore backup, install applications. I ended up with 2.5 GB free of 7.2 GB.

Comment: @ZDF thanks, that does not sound very hopeful. .. I went away 2 years ago from Android to WP, but it seems Android was not as bad compared to Android after a few years of use, considering all my other issues (very slow, SD Card always shows corrupt, updates barely install, lots of crashes, unavailability of many apps)

Comment: I am using IOS, Android and Windows. Every OS has its share of problems. My day to day phone is an old IPhone.

Comment: @ZDF you might want to consider adding that as an answer :)

Comment: @RowlandShaw See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, Windows Update cannot handle low free space situations in a satisfactory manner (I had the same problem with Android). The only way I was able to solve the space/update problem was:

1. Backup.
2. Factory reset.
3. Update.
4. Restore backup.
5. Install applications.

On my Lumia 640/Windows 10 I ended up with 2.5 GB free of 7.2 GB.